# Masonry auto adjust when the height of an item changes

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using masonry to layout items and in the case that the description is too long it displays a read more link. This open the rest of the text in an accordion style . Here is an example: http://www.ninesixty.co.nz/cubadupa18/?post_type=marcato_artist

How can I force the masonry to readjust to suit this?

Here is the mnasonry code

```
        jQuery(window).load(function() {

  // MASSONRY Without jquery
  var container = document.querySelector('#masonry-content');
  var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
    itemSelector: '.grid_4',
    columnWidth: '.grid_4',                
  });  

    });
```

Here is the readmore code:
        // DOM Ready
        $(function() {

```
        var $el, $ps, $up, totalHeight;

        $(".sidebar-box .button").click(function() {

            // IE 7 doesn't even get this far. I didn't feel like dicking with it.

            totalHeight = 0

            $el = $(this);
            $p  = $el.parent();
            $up = $p.parent();
            $ps = $up.find("p:not('.read-more')");

            // measure how tall inside should be by adding together heights of all inside paragraphs (except read-more paragraph)
            $ps.each(function() {
                totalHeight += $(this).outerHeight();
                // FAIL totalHeight += $(this).css("margin-bottom");
            });

            $up
                .css({
                    // Set height to prevent instant jumpdown when max height is removed
                    "height": $up.height(),
                    "max-height": 9999
                })
                .animate({
                    "height": totalHeight
                });

            // fade out read-more
            $p.fadeOut();

            // prevent jump-down
            return false;

        });

    });
```

I'm new to jQuery and Javascript so please try to any suggestions easy to understand.

Comment: what's the password?

Comment: Password: cubadupa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call the masonry function once again to *refresh* it.

`jQuery('#masonry-content').masonry();`

You can put that in the animation callback if you want <s>or the fadeOut callback.</s>

```
        .animate({
                "height": totalHeight
            },500,function(){
             //Callback - after the animation is over
            jQuery('#masonry-content').masonry();
        });
```